# Clustering words with Kmeans

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, k-means

How do I cluster terms (1-2 words) using Kmeans. I read a research paper where they had used K Means to cluster similar terms using Levenshtein Distance. Please help me by showing a sample code.

Thank you

Note: In the research paper they had computed the similarity matrix using Levenshtein Distance and used it for clustering.

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7765062/

Comment: What do you mean by "similar"? Is it "similar" in meaning or "similar" as in alphabets that form the word?

Comment: Similar in syntactic terms, i.e alphabetic form.That is why I wrote Levenshtein distance

Comment: Can you share the link of that paper? I may help!

Comment: Sure, https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7765062/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from nltk.metrics import distance
import scipy.spatial as spatial
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans

# sample vocabulary list
words = ['test', 'text', 'best', 'fast', 'context', 'boost', 'faster', 'border']

# similarity matrix
word_vectors = np.array([
    [
        distance.edit_distance(w, _w)
        for _w in words
    ]
    for w in words
], dtype=np.float)

centroids, _ = kmeans(word_vectors, k_or_guess=3)

word_clusters = np.argmin([
    [spatial.distance.euclidean(wv, cv) for cv in centroids]
    for wv in word_vectors
], 1)

for k in range(centroids.shape[0]):
    print('k =', k)
    print([word for i, word in enumerate(words) if word_clusters[i] == k])
```

It results as:

```
k = 0
['faster', 'border']
k = 1
['test', 'text', 'best', 'fast', 'boost']
k = 2
['context']
```

Remarks:

1. Original vocabulary works as a feature list. The list of distance measures to other words works as a feature vector to any phrase or word.
2. Each cluster is made in such feature space. Consequently, the distance between two words is not their Levenshtein Distance anymore but it is their distance in such space. This is why we use other measures such as `spatial.distance.euclidean`.
3. Kmean produces centroids in this feature space, each word is considered as a member to a cluster if the cluster centroid is the closest to the word (out of all other centroids). `np.argmin([...], 1)` is finding such assignment for each word.
4. Other clustering algorithms can be also tested on word-feature space. (List of some clustering algorithms in scikit-learn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html)

Comment: Awesome, just wanted to ask will it work for terms consisting of multiple words like ‘fast person’

Comment: It works but this depends on how you want to define the distance in multiple words. Also if you notice, the feature matrix depends on the size of the vocabulary. So, new words (including phrases) must be compared with the original word list that constructed the clusters.

Comment: I have a few questions. It would be very helpful if you could answer them. Firstly the documentation of scipy says:'scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(obs, k_or_guess, iter=20, thresh=1e-05, check_finite=True)' here obs is a M*N array of observations meaning the data points and not the similarity matrix then how is this code working correctly?

Comment: Secondly, you have used the euclidean distance, why is that?

Comment: Also, instead of K-Means can we use EM? Expectation Maximization?

Comment: I tried to include a list of remarks about your follow up questions. I hope it answers your questions.

Comment: Thanksss, it helped a lot :D

Comment: So, basically I can use any algorithm https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) of these and instead of the feature vector give the similarity matrix just like your approach and it will work?And with any of these algorithms like Gausian methods, I have to use the euclidean distance in the word-feature space?

Comment: This is my last question, sorry to bother you!

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use any clustering algorithm. But it might be challenging if you use large vocabulary. In a smaller set of vocabulary set, you may find it strange since different sets create different clusters. (e.g. `test, context, text => [test, text],[context]`
`korean, context, text => [korean],[context, text]`). Euclidean distance in a natural distance measure in vector spaces. Unless an analysis about this feature-space proves otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_levenshtein_distance(word1, word2):
word2 = word2.lower()
word1 = word1.lower()
matrix = [[0 for x in range(len(word2) + 1)] for x in range(len(word1) + 1)]

for x in range(len(word1) + 1):
    matrix[x][0] = x
for y in range(len(word2) + 1):
    matrix[0][y] = y

print(matrix)
```

Comment: Sir, my question wasn't on how to compute the Levenshtein distance matrix. I was on how to cluster the terms based on the Levenshtein similarity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is initialized measuring in the (m,n)-cell the Levenshtein distance between the m-character prefix of one with the n-prefix of the other word. The matrix can be filled from the upper left to the lower right corner.